# How to use host USB modem/internet from a virtual-box running slack?

Tags: usb, virtualbox, modem, slackware

The modem is Huawei MT882 on Windows via USB interface. This modem receives an IP over DHCP from the ISP. 
How do I get Slack on VirtualBox to recognize the presence of a USB modem, and configure it so it is able to use the internet connection on the host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand the question correctly, and you're not trying to passthrough the modem directly to the guest, you'd probably need to use the NAT networking option on virtualbox.

Comment: NAT is enabled ...